# Sliders In Divi Are Making The Page Scrolling Jittery In Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, divi

https://staging.thefuselight.com/ - When the page is scrolled past a slider element (eg. the testimonials block; and the Image Carousel block), the slider elements are forcing the scrolling to snap up to the slider element.
The user can effectively force the scrolling to resume. When it gets to the bottom of the page it tries to snap it to the above carousel making it impossible to get to footer.
I haven't see the same problem in Firefox.
This is a Loom of what's happening: https://www.loom.com/share/a5e6740ee55e41d1ad376602b82bdbaf

Has anyone seen this? Does anyone have a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Shawn

I tried making some changes to the settings inside of Divi. I looked for what was happening code-wise, but I couldn't catch if there was anything like a ScrollTo happening.

Answer (score 0):

Self inflicted wound:

This function was meant to adjust the logo on scrolling. It was causing the jerking scolling because the header kept shrinking and adjusting the content height downward. I commented out the window.onscroll() event and it now works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {       
    // window.onscroll = function() {logoAdjust()};
    window.onresize = function() {logoAdjust()};
    
    function logoAdjust() {     
        var logo = jQuery(".logo img");     
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 1 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 1) {
          var s = 18 - Math.min(12, (jQuery(document).scrollTop() / 18));
          logo.stop().animate({"width": s + "rem"}, 5);
        } else {
            logo.stop().animate({"width": "200px"}, 5); 
        }
    }   
}); 
</script>
```